# Password protected directory by ht access is redirecting to site root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

In my server the site root directory i put a .htaccess file to re write the url. Then i created a directory in the root named 'for_clinent_only'. Everything is working fine. Then i made the 'for_clinent_only' directory password protected from server cpanel. Now if i brows this directory http://www.ilcusa.org/for_clinent_only/ then it redirect me to http://www.ilcusa.org/.

The url re-write code is

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

if i remove the rewrite code then i can brows www.ilcusa.org/for_clinent_only/  link again

i searched in the web and tried put some code there but non of the

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^for_clinent_only  - [L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

also tried

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/for_clinent_only
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And i also followed this serverfault.com/questions/410445/excluding-a-directory-from-a-root-htaccess-rewrite-rule-to-allow-it-to-be-passw links suggestions  but none of this did not worked, 
Can anyone help me solve this problem.

Comment: 1) in the third set `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^for_clinent_only` w/o leading slash. 2) it sends `301 Moved Permanently` that is not in the rules